# Piping the result of ls to tail

Tags: ls, tail

I have a directory with a bunch of log files. Something like this:

```
data170213.log
data170214.log
data170215.log
data170216.log
```

I'm interested in looking at the last entries of the most recent file and following it. If I know the most recent file is **data170216.log**, I can do that with

```
tail -f data170216.log
```

The problem is, I don't know what the name of the most recent file in the directory is. I can identify it though with

```
ls -1r *.log | head -1
```

What I can't work out is how to send the result of the command **ls -1r *.log | head -1** to the command **tail -f [FILE]**

I tried the following, unsuccessfully

```
tail -f < ls -1r *.log | head -1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

```
tail -f "$(ls -1r *.log | head -n 1)"
```

This runs `ls -1r *.log | head -n 1` in a subshell, takes its output, and builds a new command using that; so if the `ls` pipe outputs `data170216.log`, the command becomes

```
tail -f "data170216.log"
```

which is what you're after.

Note `head -n 1` instead of `head -1`; the latter form is deprecated now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `xargs` in such cases. May be the simple and easy one is:

```
$ ls -1r *.log | sed -n 1p | xargs tail -f
```

Or:

```
$ ls -1r *.log | head -1 | xargs tail -f
```

Both work fine.

See `man xargs`

**EXAMPLES**:

Find files named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them.  Note that this will work incorrectly if there are any filenames containing newlines or spaces:

```
find /tmp -name core -type f -print | xargs /bin/rm -f
```

Find  files named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them, processing filenames in such a way that file or directory names containing spaces or newlines are correctly handled:

```
find /tmp -name core -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```

Find  files named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them, processing filenames in such a way that file or directory names containing spaces or newlines are correctly handled:

```
find /tmp -depth -name core -type f -delete
```

Find files named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them, but more efficiently than in the previous example (because we avoid the need to use fork(2) and exec(2) to launch rm and we don't need the extra xargs process)

Generates a compact listing of all the users on the system:

```
cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd | sort | xargs echo
```

Launches  the  minimum number of copies of Emacs needed, one after the other, to edit the files listed on xargs' standard input.  This example achieves the same effect as BSD's -o option, but in a more flexible and portable way:

```
xargs sh -c 'emacs "$@" < /dev/tty' emacs
```